# OSGi bundle with ThreadPoolTaskExecutor does not shut down gracefully

Tags: multithreading, spring, osgi, threadpool, eclipse-virgo

I am using Eclipse Virgo Server as my OSGi container and my bundle has a Spring provided `ThreadPoolTaskExecutor`. When I run the server `shutDown.bat` it will throw me an error and hangs up. I do use the `threadPoolTaskExecutor.shutDown()` in my code. It seems server hangs before it get called.

Can anyone please explain me why this happens? It seems to me I am not handle the threads correctly.

Comment: If you provide the error (stack trace?) we will have a much greater chance of helping you.

Comment: @forty-two - Thank you very much for your turn around.actually i figure out the issue. in my initializing class i used a endless for loop, keep it sleep for 1 min to simulate the folder poling. so when i use 'shutdown.bat' the looping thread will block the other threads from the thread pool and leads to a dead lock situation. so i removed that endless loop part and came up with a idea of use spring scheduling mechanism. once the loop removed i can shut down the pool executors without any issue. appreciate your interest regarding this..Thank you very much.